# Flutter make a dice rolling animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Im working on modifying a simple dice roller app in flutter as a challenge to start learning the language more.  One thing I would like to do is make a rolling animation for the dice.  As an example Im trying to do something similar to the google dice roller tool.  If you go to google search and just search for "4d8" you will see what I would like to do.

Not sure even the approach to take for this or where to start with flutter and animations or how to do that kind of animation.  So any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.  Thanks